# Amount not increasing or decreasing

Tags: php, html

I have a`PHP` CODE that looks like the one below. The idea is for users to be able to enter an amount and when the click on `update` the item will update. But the problem is, that my code is not working.

**php**

```
<?php
session_start() 
?>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['length']) && isset($_POST['Qty']) && isset($_POST['Category'])){   

 $pid = $_POST['pid'];
$length = $_POST["length"];
$qty = $_POST['Qty'];
$Category = $_POST['Category'];
    **They are more codes below in this PHP tag which just check if the
    item the user is adding is already in the basket and if not it should add it.**

  }
 ?>
```

**Adjust the Quantity of an item *(this is the code I am having the problem with)***

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $array_key=>$each_item) { 
              if ($each_item['item_id'] == $item_to_adjust  && $each_item['length'] == $length && $each_item['Category'] == $Category) {
                      $_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']+=$quantity;
                  } 
              } 
}
?>
```

***HTML***

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="Update" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form>
```

**I HAVE TRY**

I have `echo` out the `$quantity` to see if the amount I have entered as pass though and It has. So I know that part of the code is working.

**Issue**
I think it something to do with my `foreach` statement but I can't find it. I have try everything I know but I can't find anything.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a `session_start` before the second chunk of code?

Comment: @andrewsi  yes I do have it

Comment: - how the first code is connected to second?

Comment: and where in html form you have rest of the fields which you check in first php code?

Comment: 2nd code looks ok so imho the quantity adding code is not run because of fail condition - please check if this condition is true

Comment: @Jerzy Zawadzki what u mean please... be more specific

Comment: loooks like last condition: if ($each_item['item_id'] == $item_to_adjust  && $each_item['length'] == $length && $each_item['Category'] == $Category) is not true so we don't reach quantity increment

Comment: @Jerzy Zawadzki what will be the best way to check this please?

Comment: sorry but I don't know your project and don't know why do you need there this condition on length & Category 
If it's needed there you still don't have this in your form

Comment: @Jerzy Zawadzki I have a shoe that comes in different sizes so lets say u added a shoe with the length(size) of 10 and u added the same shoe with the length of 12 but then u wanted to buy 2 pairs of the 10 length and then u adjust it to 2... It should only adjust the one u want not all the shoes. also the shoe have the same "ID". Hopefully this gives u an idea. When i remember the `length & Category` the item does adjust but so does any item with the same length. The category is like the colour of the shoe like red, yellow, etc

Comment: so you need to put Category and length values (additional to item_to_adjust which you already have) to your form

Comment: @Jerzy Zawadzki can you put that in an answer so i can tick it off. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing Category and length values in your form.
In current situation your condition in foreach is going false.

Comment: I added like this to the form `<input name="length" type="hidden" value="' . $length . '" />`

Comment: yes - both category and length - however you need this data also in session as this determines your product (id-category-length)

Comment: so i need to post `category-length` in the adjust quantity php tag?

Comment: it not working, I have added Category and length value to the form and posted it to the php tag `if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && isset($_POST['size']) && isset($_POST['type'])) {
 $type = $_POST['type']; // this is the category
 $size = $_POST['size']; // this is the length`